# How to fix "Class name is not defined" error in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Good Evening, I'm having some trouble with my code. My objective here is to input data into a class. So I have p1 = Pitch("CH", "S"). From here I want to run a function that prints a statement with this data entered with another function that finds the avg speed also inside the print statement. My bad if this isn't making to much sense but let me post my code that I have so far to see if it gives a better visual.

```
import csv

fh = open('pitches.csv')
spreadsheet = csv.DictReader(fh)

startspeed = []

class Pitch:
    def __init__(self, name, result):
        fh = open('pitches.csv')
        self.spreadsheet = csv.DictReader(fh)
        self.name = name
        self.result = result

    def avg_start_speed(self):
        for row in spreadsheet:
            if row['pitch_type'] == str(self.name) and row['type'] == str(self.result):
                startspeed.append(row['start_speed'])
        return sum(startspeed) / len(startspeed)


    def myfunc(self):
        for row in spreadsheet:
            if row['pitch_type'] == self.name:
                print("The average speed of a " + self.result + " for a "
                    + self.name + " is " + str(self.avg_start_speed()))

p1 = Pitch("CH", "S")
p1.myfunc()
```

I am receiving this error

> NameError: name 'avg_start_speed' is not defined

I'm not sure how to fix it. Thanks for all advice in advance.

CSV sample:

```
start_speed end_speed   type    pitch_type
92.9    84.1    S   FF
92.8    84.1    S   FF
94.1    85.2    S   FF
91  84  B   FF
75.4    69.6    B   CU
92.9    84.8    S   CH
93.3    85.3    B   FF
89.3    82.4    X   FC
92.1    85  S   CH
```

Comment: Please show a traceback and fix either your question or your title. They don't match.

Comment: Use `self.avg_start_speed()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some issues in your code .

- You are missing a `self` argument in `def avg_start_speed():` assuming you want to use it as a class method. (I see you using `self` inside the function definition as well).
  So it will be `def avg_start_speed(self):`
- You also want to call the function `avg_start_speed()` using `self` in `myfunc` like `self.avg_start_speed()`
- You also  define `spreadsheet` outside the class. Why not define it inside the class, maybe within `__init__` and use it?
- You don't declare `startspeed` variable within `avg_start_speed()` function as well

Always remember, for class methods, the first argument is always `self`, and you call them inside other class methods within the class using `class.func()`

Taking those changes to effect, the code will look like

```
import csv

class Pitch:
    def __init__(self, name, result, spreadsheet):
        self.spreadsheet = spreadsheet
        self.name = name
        self.result = result

    def avg_start_speed(self):
        #Calculate average speed and return
        startspeed = []
        for row in self.spreadsheet:
            if row['pitch_type'] == self.name and row['type'] == self.result:
                startspeed.append(float(row['start_speed']))
        return sum(startspeed) / len(startspeed)


    def myfunc(self):

        #Call avg_start_speed here and print it using string.format
        avg_start_speed = self.avg_start_speed()
        print("The average speed of a {} for a {} is {}".format(self.result,self.name ,
            avg_start_speed))

#Open pitches.csv outside the class
with open('pitches.csv') as fh:
    #Open the csv as a dict and pass it as an argument to Pitch
    spreadsheet = csv.DictReader(fh)
    p1 = Pitch("CH", "S", spreadsheet)
    p1.myfunc()
```

So if the `pitches.csv` looks like

```
start_speed,end_speed,type,pitch_type
92.9,84.1,S,CH
94.1,85.2,S,CH
```

The output will be

```
The average speed of a S for a CH is 93.5
```

Comment: Ok, I made your changes however, im getting this traceback message: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jmmci\OneDrive\Documents", line 32, in <module>
    p1.myfunc()
  File "C:\Users\jmmci\OneDrive\Documents", line 29, in myfunc
    + self.name + " is " + str(self.avg_start_speed()))
  File "C:\Users\jmmci\OneDrive\Documents", line 21, in avg_start_speed
    startspeed.append(row['start_speed'])
KeyError: 'start_speed'     Any ideas? @Devesh

Comment: Perhaps you are not reading the csv correctly, or there is no key called start_speed in your dictionary. Can you double check. Also please add the contents your csv in the question @Sam. Also add your updated class according to the suggestion I made at the end of the question too

Comment: Ok I posted the updated script, however I'm still not sure what you mean by updating the question, what should I change it to? Also, you did mention moving my spreadsheet inside the class, do i just put it before self.name = name? @Devesh

Comment: Add the contents of pitches.csv to the question. Yes move those two lines in the init function and do self.spreadsheet @Sam

Comment: Let’s add how your csv looks like to the question first @Sam add the contents of the csv in the question

Comment: hmm ok I think I changed the question correctly? And I doubled checked the key and it is called start_speed. Is there anything else you notice @Devesh

Comment: Please add the csv to the question, there might be something else going on @Sam

Comment: Ok I wasn't sure how to add the file, so I added a picture if that helps @Devesh

Comment: copy the contents of csv and paste it to question @Sam

Comment: For some reason its only letting me post it as an image, however was able to copy a  portion of the contents if this helps @Devesh

Comment: Okay I have updated the code, it should work now @Sam

Comment: Ahh ok now I see what you meant! Thanks for helping me out! @Devesh